# Avoid clearing the splash screen

Tags: windows-ce, splash-screen, windows-embedded

How can I avoid clearing the splash screen before the desktop is up?
After the splash screen is cleared there is a white screen for two seconds I wish to avoid.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you're referring to Windows CE or an embedded edition of one of the desktop OSes (Windows XP Embedded, Windows 7 Embedded, etc)?

Comment: I'm working on Windows CE 7 system.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your display drive to ensure that it uses the same video-memory area used by the bootloader (this may already be the case) and ensuring that it doesn't erase its frame buffer on startup.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to this. Can you refer me were to look or find data I can read about it?

Comment: It's not easy to provide good references without knowing something more about your HW platform and BSP. You should look at the display driver initialization code but, depending on how is your BSP organized and on how it uses standard OS libraries the location of this code may change.

Comment: I understand, what data do you need?

Comment: It's not so easy to tell. Knowing what BSP you are using may be good, but I don't know each and every BSP, so I may not able to provide 100% accurate info. You should try to find source code of your display controller driver.